# Accessing MongoDB during server side rendering page in redux-wrapped Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I was exploring the nextjs example [`with-redux-wrapper`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper) where they show how to create a nextjs react app with redux-wrapper and server side rendering.

I want to load some data from a MongoDB collection at request time. This can be easily done using client-side data fetching (e.g. with fetch/swr). However, if the requirement needs data to be loaded with the page itself, then it makes sense to use of server side rendering features of NextJS.

Note that [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) (two notes at the bottom of the section) advise against making **local** api calls to fetch data with REST  inside of `getServerSideProps()` and suggests using the same backend api code inside there.

Now, if I use a simple nextjs app and wrap mongodb connection/queries in `getServerSideProps()`, it works as expected. However, when the `with-redux-wrapper` example is used, the mongodb libraries end up forcing client side to look for libraries meant for server side, causing the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/gssapi.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'
null
```

My confusion is:

1. Dead code elimination should remove code intended for server-side rendering from client side ([source](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9#dead-code-elimination-for-typeof-window-branches)). In that case, shouldn't mongo db client work as expected when call initiates from `getServerSideProps()`? I am even wrapping with a `typeof window === 'undefined'` check to ensure it only executes in the server.
2. The whole experience works when redux is not used. Why does it break when redux(-wrapper) is used? How can it be fixed?

P.S. I know we can use webpack config to inject empty libraries for the missing ones but that seems more like a hack and not a solution. I wonder how secure/concrete this method is.